# How to list available space excluding mount points in home directories?

Tags: command-line, bash

I ran `df -lP` which gave me the following output:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1             7.6G  2.2G  5.1G  30% /
varrun                506M  108K  506M   1% /var/run
varlock               506M     0  506M   0% /var/lock
udev                  506M   44K  506M   1% /dev
devshm                506M   12K  506M   1% /dev/shm
lrm                   506M   40M  467M   8% /lib/modules/2.6.24-26-generic/volatile
gvfs-fuse-daemon      7.6G  2.2G  5.1G  30% /home/vmadmin/.gvfs
```

How can I remove the line where it says `/home/"can be anything"`?

I can't use `df -lP | sed '$d'` because the output would be

```
Filesystem         1024-blocks      Used Available Capacity Mounted on
/dev/sda1              7867856   3622668   3845524      49% /
tmpfs                   513448         0    513448       0% /lib/init/rw
udev                    507692       124    507568       1% /dev
tmpfs                   513448         4    513444       1% /dev/shm
```

Comment: I do not yet know what your question is?. Are you trying to exclude your home folder?

Comment: @LuisAlvarado It was burried in the console output - I've reformatted the post and a question appeared! :)

Comment: `/home/"can be anything"` means `/home/`, followed by any string of characters. It's the last line in the first block of output.

Comment: `df -lP | sed '$d'` deletes the last line, as intended. I'm not sure why you're getting your results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading your question now, a simple solution would be:

`df -lP | grep -v '/home/'` Where **/home** is the one you do not want to see and the **-v** in grep will give you the inverse of what you are searching. Basically you would be telling grep to search for all line that DO NOT have the `/home` with them.

If you want to be able to exclude other folders then do the following:

`df -h | grep -ve "/home" -ve "/lib"`

This would exclude all `/home` folders and all `/lib` folders. You can continue to add excluded folder by adding **-ve** and in "" the folder you wish to exclude.

Comment: yes that comand  "df -lP | grep -v "\/home"" done that i was wanting=)

Answer (score 4):

How about this?

```
df -lP | grep -v "%\s\/home\/"
```

It filters all lines matching `%`, followed by *single-whitespace-character* and followed by `/home/` by using `grep`.

Note to other readers: as already in the question it's important to use `-P` in `df` to keep predictable single-lined output.

Comment: yes it work fine. it was what i was looking for. thanks very much=).